# SEO: Redirect root to a sub-dir, build new content on root, keep old rankings for redirected sub-dir

Tags: seo, google, redirects, 301-redirect, 302-redirect

I want to move our page from `site.example` to `www.site.example/home` but keep the SEO rankings from when that same content resided on the root domain.

Then I want to build back up the `site.example` domain level page to be an entirely different page with different content, and for it to get its own rankings, all while keeping the rankings for the redirected page on `/home`.

We were thinking to move an identical page to `/home`, then put in a 301 or 302 redirect on the root domain.  Then, sometime later, remove the redirect to have an alternate homepage begin getting indexed for its own content and keywords.

How do I keep the juice going from root to the new page in the future, when I ultimately recreate another page at the root?

Comment: I'm not sure that redirecting away from your home page root URL to a deep URL is ever a good idea.   It looks awful.